# Set resolution of WebcamTexture on WebGL build Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, webcam, unity-webgl

I've this app for Windows to switch over to WebGL.

For the Webcam Resolution I need a 16:9 resolution.

My code that works in editor, Windows and Android builds:

```
    public IEnumerator RefreshCamera()
    {
        if (camTexture != null)
        {
            Display.texture = null;
            camTexture.Stop();
            camTexture = null;
        }
        else
        {

            WebCamDevice device = WebCamTexture.devices[currentCamIndex];
            camTexture = new WebCamTexture(device.name, 576, 1024, 24);
            camTexture.requestedHeight = 576;
            camTexture.requestedWidth = 1024;
            camTexture.requestedFPS = 24;
            Display.texture = camTexture;
            camTexture.Play();
        }

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
```

While I am setting the requested resolution when setting the camTexture variable this does not work on any platforms and defaults to 480 x 640. The lines that follow however seem to do the trick on Windows, editor and android.

WebGL always defaults to 480 x 640.

I've seen on documentation that IOS does not support requestedHeight/requestedWidth but there's no mention of WebGL to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Unity WebGL bug.
To get web camera info in a browser, Unity uses the next code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: false,
        video: videoInputDevices[deviceId].deviceId ? {
            deviceId: { exact: videoInputDevices[deviceId].deviceId }
    } : true
}).then(function(stream) {...}
```

Unity doesn't request the camera capabilities and getUserMedia() returns the minimum available resolution (640x480).
We should set custom constraint for [getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#using_getusermedia). For example:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: false,
        video: videoInputDevices[deviceId].deviceId ? {
            deviceId: {
                exact: videoInputDevices[deviceId].deviceId
            },
            width: {  min: 640, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
            height: { min: 480, ideal: 720, max: 1080 },
    } : true
}).then(function(stream) {...}
```

You can add this code in your [projectname].framework.js file (need to be repeated after every build) or possibly override JS_WebCamVideo_Start method with **mergeInto** function.

Comment: Thank you so much! Fixed it right away by modifying the framework.js. May I please ask how you stumbled upon this? I searched everywhere for this information.

Comment: Unity uses [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) for all browser interactions. If you need a solution for WebGL, you need to find how it is implemented there using JS and then compare how it is implemented in Unity.